# How can I create more colors for my plot?

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot, jupyter-notebook

I was trying to make a plot using pyplot in matplotlib with 12 different lines, however there seems to be only 10 different colors leading to duplicates in two of the colors. I have tried using plt.set_cmap('Set3') to get more colors available but nothing changed. What should i do? I am fairly new to programming so I could be missing something I haven't learned yet.

Here's the code that I'm using

```
import netCDF4 as nd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

data = []
for k in range(1,13):
    nc_file = f'./MIMOC/MIMOC_ML_v2.2_CT_SA_MLP_month{k:02d}.nc'
    with nc.Dataset(nc_file) as nc_fid:
        lat = nc_fid['LATITUDE'][:]
        lon = nc_fid['LONGITUDE'][:]
        temp = nc_fid['CONSERVATIVE_TEMPERATURE_MIXED_LAYER'][:,:]
    data.append(temp)
    
months = ['January', 'Febuary', 'March', 'April', 'May', 'June', 'July', 'August', 'September', 'October', 'November', 'December']

for i in data:

    plt.plot(lat, i[:,660], label = months)

plt.legend(months, loc = 'right', bbox_to_anchor=(1.53,0.83), ncol=2)
plt.xlabel('latitude')
plt.ylabel('temperature [degC]')
plt.title('Monthly surface temperature along 30W')
plt.show()
```

Comment: What I'm mainly wondering about is how to change the colormap of this plot to include more colors

 plt.plot(lat, i[:,660], label = months)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want to set the color cycle, not `plt.set_cmap` (which sets the color map used for images https://matplotlib.org/3.3.3/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.set_cmap.html?highlight=set_cmap)

```py
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib
from cycler import cycler

cm = plt.get_cmap('Set3')


# you can also set line style, width
matplotlib.rcParams["axes.prop_cycle"] = cycler(
    color=[cm(v) for v in np.linspace(0, 1, 12)]
)

x = np.arange(5)

fig, ax = plt.subplots(constrained_layout=True)
for j in range(24):
    ax.plot(x, x + j, label=f'line {j}')

ax.legend(ncol=2)
plt.show()
```

However, if you are already looping over you data, you may be better off directly setting the color rather than relying on the `prop_cyle` (particularly if you want to make multiple plotting calls to different axes that you want to keep in sync).

[image: 12 color cycle]

https://matplotlib.org/3.3.3/tutorials/introductory/customizing.html#dynamic-rc-settings

https://matplotlib.org/3.3.3/gallery/color/color_cycle_default.html

https://matplotlib.org/cycler/